# Unkown display,xrandr badmatch,resolution undetected

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a somewhat strange monitor with a resolution of `1280x390`.
When connected to my PC through HDMI it automatically sets itself up as a `1280x1024`.

Below I have tried to add as much information as possible:

see output of `xrandr` below (`DP-1`).

```
:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  40.01  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Hardware:

```
:~$ lspci -vk | grep -iA15 vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at e3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_390, nvidia_390_drm
```

Content of `get-edid | parse-edid`:

```
:~$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 6
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
No byte reading on this bus...
Problem requesting slave address: Bad file descriptor
1 potential busses found: 5
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 5
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier ""
    ModelName ""
    VendorName "GSD"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 3 of 2005
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 340 270
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-71
    VertRefresh 56-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 110MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 640x480, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 800x600, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1024x768, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    Modeline     "Mode 0" 108.00 1280 1328 1440 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection
```

I have upgraded to the latest Nvidia driver, which at the moment of writing is `390.30`.
I also tried to connect the monitor via DVI cable without any success.

I also tried to create the resolution using xrandr.

```
:~$ cvt 1280 390
# 1280x390 59.89 Hz (CVT) hsync: 24.38 kHz; pclk: 39.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x390_60.00"   39.00  1280 1320 1440 1600  390 393 403 407 -hsync +vsync

:~$ xrandr --newmode "1280x390_60.00"   39.00  1280 1320 1440 1600  390 393 403 407 -hsync +vsync

:~$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1280x390_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

I can not seem to find anywhere on the internet what the above error actually means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The side doesn't appear to have any (modern) questions regarding forcing undetected resolutions.  If you solved this, please post your procedure!